# Unit Testing Typescript In Visual Studio for Angular 2 development

Tags: unit-testing, visual-studio-2013, typescript, jasmine, angular

I am new to angular2. Hence we are writing code in Typescript for our website. We are using Visual studio 2013 for the development. Now we need to write Unit Test cases for the Typescript code we have written.
Can someone please share a step by step example on how to configure typescript unit testing in visual studio. And whether should we write unit test cases for typescript in typescript, or we should write unit test cases for typescript in Javascript.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: +1. Its annoying to see so much documentation and tons of libraries - jasmine, chutzpah, tsUnit, Qunit, Mocha, Chai, Karma (the list goes on)  out there but not one step by step guide how to unit test a HTML Application with Typescript.

Answer (score 0):

Have you seen this: https://github.com/Steve-Fenton/tsUnit

"tsUnit is a unit testing framework for TypeScript, written in TypeScript. It allows you to encapsulate your test functions in classes and modules."

While this does not provide "step-by-step" directions ... it could be a step in the right direction!

Comment: is there a better way to do this yet?

Comment: If you are referring to Angular, then yes: https://angular.io/guide/testing

Comment: thank you I will look into it, I'm referring to unit testing angular in visual studio